# Configure View Path in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have started from skeleton app and I am trying to customize this to my liking. I don't like the folder structure as it seems to have a lot of redundancy / inconsistency.

As for my current problem I would like to keep all my views in a structure like this :

```
├── module
    ├── view
        ├── controller
            ├── action.phtml
```

What skeleton app currenly forces is this :

```
├── module
    ├── view
        ├── module      [This is what I want to get rid of , it is redundant]
            ├── controller
                ├── action.phtml
```

I do see you have configuration options:

```
'template_path_stack' => [ $dir . '/../view',  ],
```

but as you can see it still assumes dir module exist under that view folder. That is what I want to avoid.

There is also a template map, but to my knowledge it allows you manipulate specific paths. I don't want to edit this field and add a new view in the map every time I add a new action

Comment: Try using the `template_map` option as part of the `view_manager` config. See [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#configuration)

Comment: you could try to write your own `Resolver`, implementing `Zend\View\Resolver\ResolverInterface` and then adding it to the `AggregateResolver`

Comment: It might seem redundant, but it does serve a purpose. If you have two modules with a controller and action named the same, the resolver wouldn't have a way of knowing which module to render `controller/action.phtml` from. The addition of the module name removes this ambiguity.

Comment: @TimFountain I am using different layout using a setLayout event. So I think separating the layout for each module has worked out. With that, this dir does not serve any purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own implementation of Zend\Mvc\View\Http\InjectTemplateListener

Just use the original code as a base and remove the lines relating to $module around line 80 (in InjectTemplateListener::injectTemplate). Removing:

```
$template   = $this->inflectName($module);
```

Should do what you require but you'll probably want to tidy up. Then attach your implementation with higher priority than

In module.php in one of your application modules

```
public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $injectTemplateListener  = new InjectTemplateListener();

    $eventManager->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface', 
                                              MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,
                                              array($injectTemplateListener, 
                                                    'injectTemplate'
                                              ),
                                              -85
    );
}
```

Alternatively you might be able to stop the original event from happening at all rather than overwriting the template as per in the above